# Trying to call a widget using a shortcode in a page but the function doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, shortcode

I am trying to use a function I found to call widgets on the wysiwyg editor on WordPress, however it doesn't seem to be working.

the short code is:

```
[wysiwyg_widget id="sidebar"]
```

The function itself is:

```
    function wysiwyg_widget( $atts ) {

      global $wp_widget_factory;

      extract( shortcode_atts( array(
          'widget_name' => "WYSIWYG_Widgets_Widget",
      'id' => null,
      ), $atts ) );

      if ( ! is_a( $wp_widget_factory->widgets[ $widget_name ], 'WP_Widget' ) ) :
          $wp_class = 'WP_Widget_' . ucwords( strtolower( $class ) );

          if ( ! is_a ( $wp_widget_factory->widgets[ $wp_class ], 'WP_Widget' ) ) :
              return '<p>' .sprintf( __( "%s: Widget class not found. Make sure this widget exists and the class name is correct" ), '<strong>' . $class . '</strong>' ) . '</p>';
          else:
              $class = $wp_class;
          endif;
      endif;

    if ( ! is_null( $id ) ) {
      $instance['wysiwyg-widget-id'] = $id;
    }

      ob_start();
      the_widget( $widget_name, $instance, array(
      'widget_id'=>'arbitrary-instance-'.$id,
          'before_widget' => '',
          'after_widget' => '',
          'before_title' => '',
          'after_title' => ''
      ) );
      $output = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
      return $output;

  }
  add_shortcode( 'wysiwyg_widget','wysiwyg_widget' );
```

Any suggestions or if there is another way to do it without a plugin? Thank you for helping in advance!